# How to do GET request with GTKMM

Tags: c++, c++11, gtk, gtkmm, gtkmm3

Please, can you give me simple example how to do GET requests with gtkmm. 
I already tried to find answer in official documentation, but it didn`t help me.
I think i need to use libsoup or Webkit, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Simple GET HTTP requests to any website.

Comment: I would suggest that you use, as you mentioned, libsoup. There's also GLib GIO. Eventually you can use libcurl or other but if you use GLib/Gtk libraries there will be less impact when running your application on different platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some C++ network library. Look into curl or curlpp, you can even use WinSOCK if you are on Windows.